# Re-attempt docker-compose logs -f when services are down?

Tags: bash, docker-compose

I commonly find myself making docker-compose environments for development purposes.

However, an annoying thing to have to do when I start up my services with `docker-compose up -d` is to have to run `docker-compose logs -f` every time all services come down.

I'd like to be able to run a script that *attempts* to run `docker-compose logs -f` and then once it succeeds, acts as it normally would. Then once the services are down, continue to retry to run until they are up again.

Does this make sense? I've tried using `watch` but that is not behaving how I'd like and trying a loop with a sleep command in it doesn't produce any useful results either.

Comment: Just `while sleep 1; do docker-compose logs -f; done` then?

Comment: I've yet to try specifically that. It works exactly as I'd like. Thank you!

Comment: @KamilCuk Could you add that as the answer to this question? I'd like to give you credit for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run a command in a loop, just:

```
while sleep 1; do docker-compose logs -f; done
```

It will run `docker-compose logs -f` every second.

`watch` clears the screen each period, so you will not see all the messages then.